# How to use the Docker's embedded DNS server for builds via docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, dnsmasq

When I run `docker-compose up`, I see that it creates a custom network for the containers. AFAIU, this makes the containers use the Docker’s [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) for resolving, which can forward DNS lookups to addresses like `127.0.0.1` on the host (e.g. when the host uses a local DNS server, such as `dnsmasq`).

However, `docker-compose` seems to use the default `bridge` network for *builds*, which makes containers use the Google's public DNS servers in case the host is configured with `127.0.0.1`, for example.

Is it possible to use the Docker's embedded DNS server for builds, like it's used for running containers?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to that you need this?  Remember that an image is supposed to be reusable in different contexts; if your build process either tries to read or write a database, will the same image still be useful if it's run against a different database container on a different system?

Comment: I just want the build to use the host's local DNS server for resolving (configured on 127.0.0.1). It works fine when running containers, but not when building them.